# Ruby zip a stream

Tags: ruby, stream, zip

I am trying to write a ruby fcgi script which compresses files in a directory on the fly and sends the output blockwise as an http response. It is very important that this compression is done as a stream operation, otherwise the client will get a timeout for huge directories.

I have the following code:

```
d="/tmp/delivery/"

# send zip header
header(MimeTypes::ZIP)

# pseudocode from here on
IO.open(d) { |fh|
    block=fh.readblock(1024)
    #send zipped block as http response
    print zip_it(block)
}
```

How do I achieve what I've written as pseudo-ruby in the above listing?

Comment: I'd like also to know this, the zipruby gem is so Java-like and rigid... I always end up spawning the external zip (which is extremely powerful, but a bit of a sad thing to do)

Comment: how did you do that? I've tried to `IO.popen("zip -0 -r -o - \"#{file_list.join('" "')}\" 2>/dev/null") { |f| print f.read(512) }` but unzip complains about invalid zip format.

Comment: you may get more traction with tar/gz

Comment: the file_list is wrong, too much quotes there. If you plan to send files with espaces use a proper function to escape them (gem "escape" or similar, also check Ruby 1.9 Shellwords)

Answer (score 1):

Tokland's idea of using the external zip command works pretty well.  Here's a quick snippet that should work with Ruby 1.9 on Linux or similar environments.  It uses an array parameter to `popen()` to avoid any shell quoting issues and `sysread`/`syswrite` to avoid buffering.  You could display a status message in the empty `rescue` block if you like -- or you could use `read` and `write`, though I haven't tested those.

```
#! usr/bin/env ruby
d = '/tmp/delivery'
output = $stdout
IO.popen(['/usr/bin/zip', '-', d]) do |zip_output|
  begin
    while buf = zip_output.sysread(1024)
      output.syswrite(buf)
    end
    rescue EOFError
  end
end
```

Comment: The question was related streaming a zip file from the web app.

Answer (score 1):

AFAYK Zip format is not streamable, at end of compression it writes something in the file header.

gz or tar.gz is better option.

Comment: How can you do that without using a shell cmd?

Comment: There is a ruby lib [minitar](http://www.assembla.com/code/breakout-control/git/nodes/lib/minitar.rb?rev=6b517b950d8b422bde46ff9697b06dfbf06a66c6), please read examples from the code.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

https://github.com/fringd/zipline.git